# Cordova AngularJS iOS $http is not called

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, http

I have a strange issue. I use Cordova(7.0.1) + AngularJS(1.49) to build iOS app(using Xcode 8.2.1) to call server with $http service.

When I test on the emulator, everything seems to be OK, but when I load the app to the device it seems like application omits all the $http calls.

The device has iOS 9 and emulator is iOS 10.

Still, I have build few apps with similar architecture and never had such a problem.

Any idea, anyone?

Br
Kris

Comment: In your config.xml, check these entries: `<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>`

Comment: yep, that was <allow-navigation href="*"/> that i was missing, how when why, i just dont know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it mays depend of how you created the project. Anyway, I write my answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config.xml` (root of your project), please add these entries:

```
<access origin="*" /> 
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

It allows your app to navigate inside of itself.